# How to return value from method without executing code using mockito

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito

```
   /*Please help  I ma trying from last 2 days but no luck. tried different solution but checkEnvironment method is not returning returning TRUE value . I want method should return value without execution of method .Please ignore compilation error if have. */
```

`enter code here`  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4Runner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { webconfix.clss })
Public class LoginControllerTest {

```
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webcontext;
        @Mock
        LoginServiceImpl serviceimpl;
        @InjectMocks
                LoginController loginController
        private MockMvc mockmvc;
        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
        @Before
            @public void Setup() throws Exception{
                
                MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
                mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standalonSetup(loginControllerTest)
                        .build;
             mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.WebAppContextSetup(webcontext)
                        .build;
                
            }
    
        @Test
            public void loginTest() throws Exception{
                LoginServiceImpl lgservice= spy( new LoginServiceImpl );
                Login lg=new Login("test");
                String requestData=objMapper.writeValueAsString(login);
                Mockito.doReturn(Boolean.TRUE).when(lgservice).checkEnvironment("abc");
                // Mockito.when(lgservice.checkEnvironment("abc")).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
                
                MvcResult result=mockMvc.perform(MockMvcBuilders.post("/login").content(requestdata).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).andExpect(status().isOk)).andReturn();
            
    
    
                
            }

    }
```

please help  I ma trying from last 2 days but no luck. tried different solution but checkEnvironment method is not returning returning TRUE value . I want method should return value without execution of method .Please ignore compilation error if have.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Mock
         LoginServiceImpl serviceimpl;
```

Check login controller declaration. Is there any bean with type :

> LoginServiceImpl

Correct me if I wrong you have interface declaration in the controller right ?